# Chrome background cover size bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I've seen plenty of threads regarding this issue but I cant seem to find a fix.

I have a div with a background image, and its size is set to cover.

It works fine on every browser and device except for mobile chrome, whenever i scroll up and down the page, the background image seems to resize. I've also noticed the weird bug where if you put `background-size:cover` before `background-image:url('')` it ignores the `background-size` attribute, but if you put it after declaring the background image, it detects the size and sets it to cover, but then has the weird re-sizing scrolling bug.

It's driving me mad! Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Propably it's just the resizing, because the address bar is just hiding and the screen gets 'bigger'?

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what the issue is. Just noticed it now, at least now I know I can figure out a way to fix it that works for my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the background cover, but when you're scrolling the page, your browser's navigation bar (address bar) is resizing. This leads to resizing of the available viewport to the. And since your background is set to cover, it tries to cover the newly available area, appearing as an image resize.

You can have multiple solutions to this.
1. Make your full size container Absolute or fixed positioned
2. Once the page is loaded, give a `height` (or `max-height`) to your container. This, once page is loaded, will keep the height of the element same even when the page is scrolled

You'll require some more tweaks depending on what the page does and what other content it might have.

This problem is similar to having cover background, and the text sentence breaks to new lines on resize, increasing the container height.

Comment: Yes, the issue was also due to the fact that my container that had the image had a `vh` height set on it, so it was trying to match the new available height. Unfortunately fixed or absolute divs were not an option, so I just figured out the size of the screen in JS, and set the height dynamically in px instead based on the screen size

Comment: glad that it worked for you. please do mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The actual solution to this is to set `html { height: 100% }` in your CSS.

Beware that this does not resolve the Chrome viewport size bug relating to the URL bar height -- that is when you scroll up and the URL bar hides, the viewport size doesn't change and `background: cover` ends up being about 50px short of actually covering the entire viewport.

You can work around this by setting `html { height: 115% }`, but this behavior may change when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar issue with a background image on chromium-browser.  When I had `background-size: cover` in my style, the image appeared to be slightly magnified, meaning that all my centering was "off" and the right hand edges of my graphic were fuzzy.
I had to take this style element out.
This problem was not present with version 65 of chromium-browser, but has bitten me with version 72